# Creating posts with links from a txt file

Tags: plugin-development, posts, hooks, wp-insert-post, embed

I have a script which scrapes articles from the web and saves the url to a .txt file. I've created a custom plugin which on activation, loops through the urls and creates a draft post with the content being an embedded article. I'm using the following code in my plugin

```
<?php
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate');
function my_plugin_activate(){
    my_plugin_install_site();
}

function my_plugin_install_site(){
    global $user_ID;
    $handle = fopen("listOfURLs.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $count = 0;
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // process the line read.
            PostCreator('test', 'post', '<iframe src="' . trim($line) . '" class="alumni-embeded-page"></iframe>');
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    // PostCreator( 'test1', 'post', '<iframe src="[link]" class="alumni-embeded-page"></iframe>' );
    // PostCreator( 'test2', 'post', '<iframe src="[link]" class="alumni-embeded-page"></iframe>' );
}

function PostCreator(
    $name      = 'AUTO POST',
    $type      = 'post',
    $content   = 'DUMMY CONTENT',
    $category  = array(1,2),
    $template  = NULL,
    $author_id = '1',
    $status    = 'draft'
) {
    $post_data = array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $name ),
        'post_content'  => $content,
        'post_status'   => $status,
        'post_type'     => $type,
        'post_author'   => $author_id,
        'post_category' => $category,
        'page_template' => $template
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data); 
}
```

The *listOfURLs.txt* file is simply a text file in the same directory with a link to an article on every line. I'm only using 5 links to test at the moment. The problem is currently the script does not create any posts when trying to use the loop. The PostCreator() method did work when I coded the method calls manually(as shown by the comments).

I'm also getting the following error when activating the plugin. Not sure it's related as it was still displayed when hard coding the method calls.

> The plugin generated 205 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Comment: [Enable debug logging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log) in your `wp-config.php` i.e. `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`, re-activate your plugin, then check `wp-content/debug.log` to find out what the cause of the unexpected output is.

Comment: I had tried that but the 'debug.log' file is never created

Comment: Possibly an environment configuration issue. Sometimes manually creating the `debug.log` file will work.

Comment: I ran the plugin on a local host and was able to debug with no problems, the way I was referencing the .txt file was incorrect. Still not sure why the debugging doesn't work on the remote server. It's hosted by my uni and I don't have access to the .ini files, so might be an issue with how the php is set up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get errors because you create duplicated posts named as "test". Postcreator function's 1rst argument should be dynamic, hot hardcoded. When you activate the plugin the loop is executed and the "generated 205 characters of unexpected ..." probably is the database error message of duplicate post

Comment: I just tried to `wp_insert_post()` 3 posts with the `post_title` "Title" on my local installation, and WP didn't bat an eye. I don't think the titles are the problem.